# InfoPath 2010 + SP2010 : Will my design work?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010, sharepoint-list

I am working on a project and I am new to InfoPath.

The requirement is employee tasks, in which every employee have to submit completion report of periodic tasks assigned to them by supervisor for each month. I have a master list of all tasks (say 50) and every employee have a template of tasks (15 out of 50 and other may just 5 of 50). The supervisor will like to see this submitted report of all employee task completion status (Emp1- 90%, Emp2- 50% of their tasks) in single page by filtering whole year data by month and can print/watch each employee’s submission report (probably a Form).

Design : I am guessing that, this project may need 3 lists for master, templates and actual monthly data and 1 InfoPath form library for submitted forms and one custom view/ form for Supervisor’s view to filter by each month.
I have MySQL Database to use if I need it.
I can do this using ASP.Net + Database but I am trying to implement this in InfoPath forms and SP2010.

I like to know whether it is possible to implement or not, if it is extendable? and I really appreciate your views and suggestions.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use Microsoft SQL Server with SharePoint 2010. You can likely store the templates in the Site Assets or Site Pages folder which is created in Site Collections by default. These folders are meant to hold files where as lists typically hold data. Other then that, yes it sounds like you can implement your design.

SharePoint workflows have a task edit item which allows users to enter in their progress by percentage, from 0 to Completed. InfoPath works great for filling out reports/business forms.